# Changing the description of a shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, metadata, windows-10-v1903

[Here](https://prnt.sc/oconz5). I can't change the file tags/metadata of a shortcut file I made.

I'm the admin, and I've already tried changing permissions on the file, that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I need some help to be able to edit them, I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: So, if the click the **Securty'** tab in the **Properties** dialog, then click **Advanced**, do Administators have Full Control?

Comment: @KeithMiller Yes. You can replicate this yourself if you're on Windows. Create a shortcut, put an URL as the location, and try changing one of the fields.

Comment: You're right. Have these properties always been a part of .url files? I wasn't aware of them.

Comment: @KeithMiller Don't know, but I'm looking for anyway I can to edit them. I tried using Powershell to set the tags, but i'm not proficient with it and gave up when I found out two commands ("get-itemproperty" and "wmic datafile where name...") don't give you file metadata as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2568750/apply-property-error-occurs-when-attempting-to-modify-either-the-ratin) is to open the shortcut in a text editor, add the following:

```
[{5CBF2787-48CF-4208-B90E-EE5E5D420294}]
Prop21=31,
```

And then the text description after the comma.